# How to remove application insights monitoring (unmap) of Web App from Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-group

I created application-insight resource(e.g- appinsight) in azure and mapped one web-app (which is under one resource group) to that application-insight for testing. Now I have to remove application insight monitoring (unmap) for that web app from azure. I am not getting option to unmap application insight for that web-app. How to unmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have been able to work out, when you link an App Insights account to a web app through the portal, the link is established using an app setting called `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`. If you look at your app settings you should see it there.

When I delete the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` app setting from a test web app, the Application Insights section of the web app no longer shows the link, so that seems to work.

Comment: Thanks. There is also one more option to unmap App Insight from your Web App i.e. Resource Explorer under Development Tools.  It will give you all XML nodes of your Web App Setting. you need to carefully remove node which you don't want.

Comment: Is there a particular node or set of nodes that should be removed if using Resource Explorer?  If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have to remove application insight monitoring (unmap) for that web app from azure.

After you selected an application insight in application insight monitoring, you could click **change**>choose Restart automatically or Restart later>Continue button to achieve your goal.
The related application insight would be removed from monitoring>application insight.

[image: cho]

Comment: If my answer is helpful, you could mark it as answer to close this thread.

Comment: I could not see a remove option there. It just shows change the appinsights instance.